# Change Table opacity when hovering on another element

Tags: css, hover, css-tables

I have simplified something (an HTA) I am working on in hopes that someone can help me (again) achieve what I am going for.

I am trying to get an entire table's styling to change when hovering over the word help. This way the tooltip will "pop" more. I have tried changing the HTML a thousand different ways but the CSS that i think should work, doesn't. I thought if I wrap the entire "help" section in a DIV then another DIV around the table I could use this

```
.help:hover ~ table { opacity:0.4;}.
```

the jsfiddle below is the only way I can get the effect i want but the table opacity goes to 0.4 no matter where I hover (assuming because its all in 1 DIV?). Hopefully this all makes sense!

```
.help:hover table {
opacity: 0.4;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6DsMg/12/ (please view this in IE only)

Comment: this is for an HTA so it has to be IE....thanks for the helpful input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working by using what I posted above. Still unsure why it isnt working in my actual finished product though. At least i know it works.

for anyone who comes across this post, the jsfiddle has been updated.